# Rules in prolog which in harmony with these natural language

Tags: syntax, prolog

**1. A parent who has exactly two children. In other word, If 'Rand' is a son of 'X', 'Rand' must be either 'A' or 'B'**

I have tried this:

```
parent2Children(Prt) :-
    son(A, Prt), 
    son(B, Prt), 
    A \= B, 
    (son(Z, Prt) -> (Z == A;Z == B)).
```

but doesn't give the expected result.

**2. A child who is the second child of any family**

The idea is if he has an older sibling called 'X', then 'X' doesn't have any older siblings. But I am confused to convert it to prolog

Let this rule called:

```
secondChild(X). /*Which will return true/yes if X is a second child of any family. Else, will return false/no*/
```

**3. A man who has children less than 2 (either have no/0 child or have only one child)**

```
less2Child(Prt) :-
    ((son(A, Prt), son(Z, Prt)) -> (A == Z));
    /* ... or he has no child (I am confused how to convert it to prolog)*/
```

***Here are some rules that can be used:***

```
male(X). /*X is a male*/
female(X). /*X is a emale*/
age(X, AgeX). /*AgeX is age of X*/
married(X, Y). /*X is married with Y, vice versa*/
son(X, Y). /*X is a son of Y (applied on both male or female)*/
siblings(X, Y). /*X is one of a sibling of Y, vice versa*/

elder(X,Y) /*X is older sibling of Y (applied on both male or female)*/
husband(X,Y) /*X is a male, and X is married with Y*/
eldest1(X) /*X is the oldest child in any family)*/
youngest1(X) /*X is the youngest child in any family*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Your solution for the first part is close. The problem is that while Prolog has a `->` built-in predicate, it doesn't do what you want. In fact, `->` alone has a very specific and very rarely useful meaning. It is mostly useful in a combination like `(Condition -> ThenPart ; ElsePart)` which is composed of `->` and `;` but different from both.

What you're trying to say is something like "if `Z` is a child of the parent, then `Z` is the same as `A` or `B`". More precisely, this is "any child of the parent must be equal to `A` or `B`". Here the word "any" is a quantifier: *for all* children `Z` something should hold. `->` is not a quantifier. Standard Prolog doesn't have quantifiers, but there is a widely supported `forall` predicate that can help:

```
two_children_2(Parent) :-
    son(A, Parent),
    son(B, Parent),
    A \= B,
    forall(son(C, Parent), (C = A ; C = B)).
```

Alternatively, you could turn the statement around and say "there is no child `Z` that is different from `A` and `B`":

```
two_children(Parent) :-
    son(A, Parent),
    son(B, Parent),
    A \= B,
    \+ ( son(C, Parent), C \= A, C \= B ).
```

The answer to part 2 depends on how exactly the database is to be interpreted. I think the only simple way to implement this if the "elder" predicate is interpreted as "older than *and neighboring*" sibling. For example, if Bart, Lisa, and Maggie are siblings, and Bart is older than Lisa, who is older than Maggie, then the database should be:

```
elder(bart, lisa).
elder(lisa, maggie).
```

But the database should *not* contain a transitive fact

```
elder(bart, maggie).
```

In this case, "second oldest child" would be "there is a next older child who is the oldest in the family".

For the third question, define two auxiliary predicates `no_children` and `exactly_one_child` describing people who have no children or exactly one child. Less than two children then just means one or the other:

```
less_than_two_children(Parent) :-
    no_children(Parent).
less_than_two_children(Parent) :-
    exactly_one_child(Parent).
```